# Can I use faiss as retrieve on recommendation system?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, information-retrieval, learning-to-rank, ann

I'm planning on using faiss to generate candidates and then lightgbm to rank the candidates.

I think about using E-commerce data, as most of the examples I see using faiss are textual data.

Is using faiss for this a good approach?